# PHP Regex - Get Text From All Links With a Specified Class

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I'm trying to use PHP and regex to grab all the hyperlinks from an external page. The links I care about scraping are structured as follows:

```
<li class="magic"><a href="http://blah.com">TargetText1</a></li>
<li class="magic"><a href="http://blah.com">TargetText2</a></li>
```

Please bear in mind I'm trying to get the anchor text NOT the url. I've got the code below working however it simply scrapes all the links on the page. I'm trying to scrape links only wrapped with the li class listed above.

```
 $url = "http://www.example.com"; 
 $input = @file_get_contents($url) or die("Could not access file: $url"); 

 $regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";

 if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches)) { 
  print_r($matches);
 }
```

Comment: dom is crap. Use XPath! `//a/text()`

Comment: I should probably mention that there are roughly 700 links on this page :/

Comment: What's not working? It seems a simple matter to extend that regex to include what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

    $dom = new domDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $lis = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
    foreach($lis  as $li){
        if($li->getAttribute('class')=='magic'){
            $links = $li->getElementsByTagName('a');
            if($links->length){
                echo $links->item(0)->nodeValue;
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Not sure but I think this grabs links with class magic instead of links nested in li with class magic?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully, I'll edited it!

Comment: Very close, just doesn't take into consideration the li class "magic"